# Convertir o SaveAs un archivo txt a archivo Excel

Tags: delphi

Estoy intentando generar un archivo Excel basado en el contenido de un archivo txt ya generado previamente, intento copiar o almacenar los mismos datos que están en el txt pero cuando genero el archivo, lo genera mal,

el txt trae algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al generarme el excel me trae algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna manera de copiar la informacion del txt generado previamente en un archivo excel o convertir el txt en un archivo excel?

Código:

```
  ...
  ...   
  public     
    { Public declarations }     
    StringGridku:TStringGrid;   
  end;

  ...

function RefToCell(ARow, ACol: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := Chr(Ord('A') + ACol - 1) + IntToStr(ARow);
end;

function SaveAsExcelFile(AGrid: TStringGrid; ASheetName, AFileName: String): Boolean;
const
  xlWBATWorksheet = -4167;
var
  efRow, efCol: Integer;
  efGridPrevFile: String;
  efXLApp, efSheet, efData: OleVariant;
  efi, efj: Integer;
begin
  efData:= VarArrayCreate([1, AGrid.RowCount, 1, AGrid.ColCount], varVariant);
  for efi:= 0 to AGrid.ColCount - 1 do
    for efj:= 0 to AGrid.RowCount - 1 do
      efData[efj + 1, efi + 1]:= AGrid.Cells[efi, efj];
    Result:= False;
    efXLApp:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    try
      efXLApp.Visible:= false;
      efXLApp.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet);
      efSheet := efXLApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets[1];
      efSheet.Name:= ASheetName;
      efSheet.Range[RefToCell(1, 1), RefToCell(AGrid.RowCount, AGrid.ColCount)].Value:= efData;
      try
        efXLApp.Workbooks[1].SaveAs(AFileName);
        Result:= true;
      except

      end;
    finally
      if not VarIsEmpty(efXLApp) then
      begin
        efXLApp.DisplayAlerts:= False;
        efXLApp.Quit;
        efXLApp:= Unassigned;
        efSheet:= Unassigned;
      end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var   
  StringListKu:TStrings;   
  efCi: integer;
begin
try
  StringListKu.LoadFromFile(ruta+FileName);
  for efCi:= 0 to StringListKu.Count - 1 do
  begin
    StringGridku.Cells[0, efCi]:= StringListKu.Strings[efCi];
  end;
  
  //esta parte es para obtener el nombre del archivo sin extension
  parsedStrings:= TStringList.Create;
  dmCommonProc.ParseDelimited(parsedStrings, FileName, '.');
  efNewFile:= parsedStrings[0] + '.xls';
  
  if SaveAsExcelFile(StringGridku, 'Sheet 1', ruta+efNewFile) then
    ShowMessage('The excel file was generated in ' + ruta+efNewFile);
finally
  StringGridku.Free;
  StringListKu.Free;
end;
end;
```

Referencia:

[Example Delphi - Export Text File to Excel File](https://dokumen.tips/documents/example-delphi-export-text-file-to-excel-file.html)

Answer (score 2):

Hay que comentar que hay varias cosas que fallan en el problema y el código que has expuesto.

Lo primero es que te basas en una función `SaveAsExcelFile`, que vuelca el contenido de un `TStringGrid` sobre un Excel. El procedimiento funciona correctamente, siempre y cuando los datos estén en el `TStringGrid` en diferentes columnas. Esas mismas columas son las que luego se trasladan a la hoja Excel.

En tu caso con este código:

```
  for efCi:= 0 to StringListKu.Count - 1 do
  begin
    StringGridku.Cells[0, efCi]:= StringListKu.Strings[efCi];
  end;
```

consigues que cada linea del fichero pase a una única celda del `TStringGrid`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto el resultado en la hoja de Excel es el equivalente. Todo va a una única coluumna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si con tu código consigues que el `TStringGrid` tenga los datos en dos columnas, por ejemplo con algo como lo que muestro a continuación, en el Excel también saldrán en dos columnas. No es un código definitivo, simplemente es de prueba para que veas en funcionamiento en 2 columnas:

```
for efCi := 0 to StringListKu.Count - 1 do
begin
  StringGridku.Cells[0, efCi]:= Copy(StringListKu.Strings[efCi], 1, 7);
  StringGridku.Cells[1, efCi]:= Copy(StringListKu.Strings[efCi], 8, 10);
end;
```

El resultado será el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fue de gran ayuda, gracias